# Local Server to Google Cloud authentication using rest API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are planning to host a topic (pub/sub) on google cloud and have created a topic and client service account.

Now I have to connect to the topic and publish the messages. I was trying to authenticate before publishing the messages. But couldn't find a suitable approach for my scenario "Local Server to Google Cloud authentication using rest API".

Please help me if there is any approach available for this method.

Here is the code I am using but is giving browser redirect response instead of access token.
Please find the code below and response

```
 private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {

      HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

      GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets  = JSON_FACTORY.fromReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))), GoogleClientSecrets.class);       

      if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
              System.out.println("Enter Client ID and Secret in client_secrets.json");
              System.exit(1);
            }


      GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
          httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
          Collections.singleton(PubsubScopes.PUBSUB)).build();

      return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL);
    }


Please open the following address in your browser:
```

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1164246778127&redirect_uri=http://localhost:53869/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the service account's JSON key file. [Check out the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#service_running_on-premises) to see how you can use this (application default credentials using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable).